# Error creating data frame with fewer elements than original dataframe-ified JSON

Tags: r, rstudio, lapply, jsonlite

```
library(jsonlite)
paths <- list.files(
  pattern="data.json",
  full.names=TRUE,
  recursive=TRUE
)
colNames = c("BillType",
             "Congress",
             "IntroducedAt",
             "OfficialTitle",
             "Number",
             "Status",
             "SubjectsTopTerm",
             "UpdatedAt")
trimData <- function(x) {
  a <- list(x$bill_type,
            x$congress,
            x$introduced_at,
            x$official_title,
            x$number,
            x$status,
            x$subjects_top_term,
            x$updated_at)
  result <- as.data.frame(a)
  return(result)
}
rawData <- do.call(
    "rbind",
    lapply(paths, function(x) fromJSON(txt = x, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE))
)
prunedData <- do.call(
    "rbind",
    lapply(rawData, function(x) trimData(x))
)
colnames(test) <- colNames
write.csv(prunedData, "test3.csv")
```

My goal with this script is to take the dataframe-ified JSON data and turn it into a slimmer data frame for CSV output. The `rawData` variable ends up having roughly ~100 columns. When I execute this script in RStudio, I get the following error:

```
> prunedData <- do.call("rbind", lapply(rawData, function(x) trimData(x)))
Error in data.frame(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(NA, "PASS_OVER:HOUSE",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 4
```

I'm not much of an expert in declarative languages like R and SQL so, if you could dumb this down for me, it would go a long way!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this JSON to data frame migration approach with a nested `do.call()` and `lapply()` commands. Outer `do.call` row binds data across files, inner `do.call` row binds json data within each file. The `paste()` collapses list data into one element, removing the EOF should your json files be pretty-printed and not compacted all on one line.

```
library(jsonlite)

paths <- list.files(pattern="data.json", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
colNames = c("BillType", "Congress", "IntroducedAt", "OfficialTitle",
             "Number", "Status", "SubjectsTopTerm", "UpdatedAt")

rawData <- do.call(rbind,
                   lapply(paths, 
                          function(x)
                          do.call(rbind, 
                                  lapply(paste(readLines(x, warn=FALSE),
                                               collapse=""), 
                                         jsonlite::fromJSON)
                          )
                   )
           )

# TRIM TO NEEDED COLUMNS
prunedData <- rawdata[colNames]
```